# What's point in receiving a `PrefixMap` and returning a empty `PrefixMap`?

Tags: scala

Here is an example from the stairway book:

```
object Example1 {

  import collection._

  class PrefixMap[T]
    extends mutable.Map[String, T]
    with mutable.MapLike[String, T, PrefixMap[T]] {
    var suffixes: immutable.Map[Char, PrefixMap[T]] = Map.empty
    var value: Option[T] = None

    def get(s: String): Option[T] = {
      // base case, you are at the root
      if (s.isEmpty) value
      // recursive
      else suffixes get (s(0)) flatMap (_.get(s substring 1))
    }

    def iterator: Iterator[(String, T)] = {
      (for (v <- value.iterator) yield ("", v)) ++
        (for ((chr, m) <- suffixes.iterator; (s, v) <- m.iterator) yield (chr +: s, v))
    }

    def +=(kv: (String, T)): this.type = {
      update(kv._1, kv._2)
      this
    }

    def -=(key: String): this.type = {
      remove(key)
      this
    }


    def withPrefix(s: String): PrefixMap[T] = {
      if (s.isEmpty) this
      else {
        val leading = s(0)
        suffixes get leading match {
          case None => {
            // key does not exist, create it
            suffixes = suffixes + (leading -> empty)
          }
          case _ =>
        }
        // recursion
        suffixes(leading) withPrefix (s substring 1)
      }
    }

    override def update(s: String, elem: T) = {
      withPrefix(s).value = Some(elem)
    }

    override def remove(key: String): Option[T] = {
      if (key.isEmpty) {
        // base case. you are at the root
        val prev = value
        value = None
        prev
      } else {
        // recursive
        suffixes get key(0) flatMap (_.remove(key substring 1))
      }
    }

    override def empty = PrefixMap.empty
  }

  import collection.mutable.{Builder, MapBuilder}
  import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

  object PrefixMap {
    def empty[T] = new PrefixMap[T]
    def apply[T](kvs: (String, T)*): PrefixMap[T] = {
      val m: PrefixMap[T] = empty
      for(kv <- kvs) m += kv
      m
    }
    def newBuilder[T]: Builder[(String, T), PrefixMap[T]] = {
      new mutable.MapBuilder[String, T, PrefixMap[T]](empty)
    }

    implicit def canBuildFrom[T]: CanBuildFrom[PrefixMap[_], (String, T), PrefixMap[T]] = {
      new CanBuildFrom[PrefixMap[_], (String, T), PrefixMap[T]] {
        def apply(from: PrefixMap[_]) = newBuilder[T]
        def apply() = newBuilder[T]
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I don't understand this line:

```
        def apply(from: PrefixMap[_]) = newBuilder[T]
```

What's point in receiving a `PrefixMap` and returning a empty `PrefixMap`?

Answer (score 0):

Read little bit more [official docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html)

If in short: CBF can return builder with knowledge of properties of whole collection.
For example it could preinitialize some buffer of needed size to collect entries.
Or even reuse some parts of collection of known type and structure.

But by default in many case it would just collect element by element to empty collection. That's happening in your case.